# Auto rotate issues in iPhone (portrait to landscape)

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I want my iphone to autoscale my website on rotation.

when I use this line of code it works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes|no" />
```

But the problem is that it activates both of my CSS for portrait and lanscape even though it should activate in landscape mode only one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobileStyles.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width : 320px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobilePortraitStyles.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
```

When I use this line instead of the meta above the css works right but no autoscale on rotation:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

What is the problem? What should I do?

Besides the meta line above I have these lines as well:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

I test that on iPhone 4 (using iOS5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [using the orientation keyword in your media queries](http://www.cloudfour.com/ipad-orientation-css/)? e.g.

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:portrait)” href=”portrait.css”>
<link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:landscape)” href=”landscape.css”>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it affects also desktop broswer (whether Height is bigger than width or the opposite)

Comment: Yes, but that's true of your other media queries too, assuming you make the window small enough! You can try adding `and (max-device-width : 480px)` (or whatever widths you need) to the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with no auto scale on rotation is an iOS bug.  Setting the max scale in the viewport seems to fix it but actually introduces as number of other issues - as you are seeing here it does not resize the viewport so does not trigger the media queries.

You might want to take a look at the [workaround](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/).